# character c cedilla ( SMALL) is displayed as CAPITAL

Tags: character-encoding, gsm, ussd, ss7

I am facing an issue when displaying the C cedilla character (`U+00E7` ç) used in French language, on a handset.

When it is sent via USSGW/SS7 as small c cedilla , it is displayed on handset as capital c cedilla (`U+00C7` Ç).

For info, the character is encoded with `gsm7bit`.

Do you have any solution or idea for this situation?

Comment: Were you able to identify the code or library that was using the old mapping?

Answer (score 1):

The original [ETSI TS 100 900 V7.2.0](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/100900_100999/100900/07.02.00_60/ts_100900v070200p.pdf) (1999-07) *Digital cellular telecommunications system (Phase 2+);
Alphabets and language-specific information
(GSM 03.38 version 7.2.0 Release 1998)* defined byte `0x09` as `Ç` (capital C with cedilla).

Subsequently in [GSM 03.38 to Unicode mappings](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ETSI/GSM0338.TXT), a clarification was made:

> General notes:
>   This table contains the data the Unicode Consortium has on how ETSI GSM 03.38 7-bit default alphabet characters map into Unicode. This mapping is based on ETSI TS 100 900 V7.2.0 (1999-07), with a correction of 0x09 to *small* c-cedilla, instead of *capital* C-cedilla.

and in the table:

```
0x08    0x00F2  #   LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH GRAVE
0x09    0x00E7  #   LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
#0x09   0x00C7  #   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA (see note above)
0x0A    0x000A  #   LINE FEED
```

So there you have it, this character was remapped at some point.  It is likely that you are correctly-encoding the character, but an older device or something using a library with the old standard is interpreting the character according to the original mapping, resulting in the capital letter.

I'm not seeing a mapping for Ç so it shouldn't appear any more.